# python class changes another class. Why?

Tags: python, class

how is that that I change class A ? 
first one prints:

```
{"s":1, "b":2}
```

second one

```
{"s":3, "b":2}
```

but i think i should get same as first one

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.g =""

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)           

class B():
    def __init__(self, classA):
        self.f = classA.g


a = A(g={"s":1, "b":2})

print (a.g)

b = B(a)
b.f["s"]=3

print (a.g)
```

Answer (score 4):

What happens in the following:

When you instantiate `b = B(a)`, your `B.__init__` method sets `b.f = a.g`.

The easier way to grasp this is to consider `a.g` and `b.f` as **references** to another object (the actual dict). This means that they *point to* an object - they *are not* the object itself.

Doing `b.f = a.g` means that `b.f` now references the same underlying object that `a.g` does, that's all.

When you do `b.f["s"]=3`, you're *modifying* the underlying object that `b.f` references.

This happens to be the same one that `a.g` references, so `a.g` is "changed" too!

---

**In reply to your comment:**

When you do `b.f={"s":3, "b":2}`, you take the following steps:

1. Create a new dictionary: `{"s":3, "b":2}`
2. Modify the `b.f` reference so that it now points to this new dictionary (and has nothing to do with the old one anymore!)

This is equivalent to:

```
new_dict = {"s":3, "b":2}
b.f = new_dict
```

The  `a.g` reference is left untouched and, hence, unchanged.
As a consequence, `a.g` and `b.f` **do not reference the same underlying object anymore**.

Comment: ..better explained, in Python mutable types (ie. pretty much everything a part form string, integer, boolean and None) is always passed by reference, not by value. In your case, I think what you want is a copy; a common way to copy dictionaries is ``newdict = dict(olddict)``

Comment: @redShadow I expected that maybe the person who asked the question is not entirely familiar with pass-by-reference and pass-by-value, but feel free to add an answer with that take! :)

Comment: To add to the above, if the desired effect is that `b.f` is a different object than `a.g`, you can make a deepcopy using [**copy.deepcopy()**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Comment: why it works like this ? a = A(g={"s":1, "b":2})

print (a.g)

b = B(a)
b.f={"s":3, "b":2}

print (a.g)You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: yeah, my comment was pretty much half-way between ThomasOrozco's answer and Junuxx's comment.. :P Anyways, I was thinking about going to sleep, that's why I didn't write a fully-featured answer :)

Comment: @user1784300 I replied to your comment in the answer!

Comment: WOW Thanks redShadow.. that's what i need

Comment: Hmmmm strange that newdict = dict(olddict) didnt work for me, but deepcopy works